# Error getting setting of my custom plugin for Redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine-plugins

Hy, everyone! 
I have an error in ruby code of my plugin for Redmine. Error occurs then method `Setting.plugin_myplugin['myplugin_setting']`
is called.

Here traceback of this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `plugin_myplugin' for #<Class:0x00000004874098>):
  activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:55:in `method_missing'
  plugins/myplugin/lib/myplugin/patches/account_controller_patch.rb:36:in `login_with_myplugin'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:447:in `_run__4412462782733274046__process_action__1678150651014813342__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
  activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
```

System specifications:

- Redmine 2.5.1
- apache2.2.22-1ubuntu1.5
- Passenger 4.0.4
- ruby 1.9.3p545

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: post what is here `plugins/myplugin/lib/myplugin/patches/account_controller_patch.rb:36`

Comment: @gotva 
This patch for the Redmine Core class: _AccountController_. It adds method _login_with_myplugin_ in the _alias_method_chain_ before the  core method _login_. Exactly in the method _login_with_myplugin_ occurs call to `Setting.plugin_myplugin['myplugin_setting']`.

More information about extending of the Redmine Core methods and classes: [Extending the Redmine Core](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Plugin_Internals)

Answer (score 2):

It is necessary to debug code.

[Here](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/ebe3a916bcc270cb52cff72739b82fc1946d9849/app/models/setting.rb#L79-L82) Redmine loads plugin settings to class variable.

[Here](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/ebe3a916bcc270cb52cff72739b82fc1946d9849/app/models/setting.rb#L124) Redmine defines setter/geter for each setting.

And exactly your method `plugin_myplugin` does not appear in `@@available_settings`. So I think you should

- check your `init.rb` file and check what plugin name you use.
- check if any settings you define there (working [example](https://github.com/twinslash/redmine_omniauth_google/blob/0af14640cbcb30f52a58b021a646431bb51419eb/init.rb#L12))
- (if previous didn't help) debug core: check why your plugin settings don't appear in `@@avaulable_settings` (I think you should debug [here](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/ebe3a916bcc270cb52cff72739b82fc1946d9849/app/models/setting.rb#L79-L82))

Answer (score 2):

This problem happened also to me.

With [@gotva's answer suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22979754/1504300) I've been able to go deeper and I understood which was the cause for me. In my case, I've got 2 plugins:

- one plugin has got its settings (registered in the standard way, i.e. calling the method `settings` inside `Redmine::Plugin.register`), and I was failing to reach its configuration page seeing the error reported in the question;
- in the other plugin I was setting a given Setting (sorry for the pun) just after having registered the plugin (i.e. after the call to `register`).

The plugin with settings was working if I was keeping only it.

Since the `Setting` class loads settings when it's used for the first time, I'm pretty sure that the problem was that the plugin in which I was using `Setting` was getting loaded before the other: so when I declared the settings, `Setting` didn't load them anymore because it was been already called, leaving out the settings that I wanted to load.